# Cause: org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl

Tags: firebase, android-studio, http-proxy, android-studio-3.2

I have connected my Android application with firebase-database by putting this dependency (kapt 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0') but after that I am getting errors like the one mentioned in title also when I synchronized the project I am getting different errors like: Connection time out, Failed to resolved build listener.

Enabling/Disabling offline work and setting proxy in gradle.properties file doesn't work for me.
Also you guys have seen that I used 'kapt' in dependency as it is necessary to use, without it I am getting error "failed to resolve 15.0.0". Removing 15.0.0 doesn't work for me.

Error

Cause:org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.tooling.util.ModuleComponentIdentifierImpl.getModuleIdentifier()Lorg/gradle/api/artifacts/ModuleIdentifier;ing

I am using Android Studio 3.2 and sadly I can't update this version.
Gradle version: 5.1.1 and
Plugin version: 3.4.0